# How do I modify a list of files in a Gradle copy task?

Tags: gradle

Warning: Gradle newbie... :-)

I'm in the process of converting an existing project from Ant to Gradle. A large portion of my project consists of code that is generated. This code is generated into an internal directory and a local build is done to ensure that the code is generated correctly. Once the local test build is verified, the generated code is copied to a set of WAR projects for final deployment.

So as part of the build, I have a task that copies files from the test build to a WAR project. While making the copy there are a few files that should only be copied if they don't already exist in the destination WAR project. To do this, I wrote the following Gradle copy task:

```
task copyServer (type: org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy) {
    group = 'ds_copy'

    String serviceRootDir = "${DS_ROOT_DIR}/NDMS_DS_Generated_Services/server_src/${x_dsServiceDir}"
    String serviceDestDir = "${DS_ROOT_DIR}/NDMS_DS_Client/srv_src/${x_dsServiceDir}"

    FileTree setupFiles = fileTree ("$serviceRootDir") {
        include "gen/**/*.java", "request/gen/**.java"
    }

    doFirst {

        File appFile = new File (serviceDestDir, "${dsName}App.java")

        if (appFile.exists () == false)
        {
            setupFiles = fileTree (dir: "$serviceRootDir", include: ["gen/**/*.java", "request/gen/**.java", "${dsName}App.java"])
        }

        println ("Copying service classes for ${dsName} from ${serviceRootDir}")
        println ("Files to copy: ")
        setupFiles.each { println (it) }
        println (setupFiles)
    }

    from (setupFiles)

    into (serviceDestDir)

    doLast {
        println ("Finished copying service classes for ${dsName}")
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't seem to update the fileTree from the *doFirst* block in order to make the check for the existence of the files in the destination. Even though I see *setupFiles* getting updated, when the copy occurs the file I added in the *doFirst* block does not get copied.

Is there any way to modify the fileTree that the copyTask is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever try to change the configuration of a task from the execution phase, especially if this changes the inputs or outputs. This will break the up-to-date checks and I think Gradle in recent versions even actively prohibits this.

Make a second task that generates your file and then make the copyServer task include the output of that task via configuration. You should not even need an explicit task dependency if you did it correctly, as it shoudl be added implicitly.

Actually your copy task should more look like

```
task copyServer(type: Copy) {
    group = 'ds_copy'

    from serviceRootDir
    into serviceDestDir
    include 'gen/**/*.java'
    include 'request/gen/**.java'
    include "${dsName}App.java"

    doLast {
        println "Finished copying service classes for $dsName"
    }
}
```

Btw. one tip for the Ant -> Gradle conversion. Learn Gradle, forget your Ant buildscript, create your build from scratch with Gradle in the Gradle way. If you try to port your existing Ant build, you will most likely end up with very ugly Gradle builds that might also be much less efficient than they could be.

Comment: Thanks. That got me to where I needed to be. I wasn't taking into account the fact that I could alter the includes at configuration time. By adding an if statement around the include clauses, I can control what gets added, just like I was trying to do at execution time before...

Comment: What is the use-case in not copying the file if it is already present?

Comment: I'm copying the file if it's *not* present in the destination directory (i.e. appFile.exists () == false)

Comment: Yes, that is what I said and asked about

Comment: The destination directory contains copies of the files needed for the service. On the initial copy the file doesn't exist in the destination, so the file should be copied. Once the initial copy has been done, its possible that the file in the destination may have been hand edited, so subsequent copies should not overwrite that file, if it already exists in the destination.